# Running storage device self-test on OS X

Tags: macos, operating-system

How do I run a device self-test on storage devices on OS X?

I want to send the ATA-level commands to perform self-test on a device -- not the SMART tools. I need to do it from C without the use of any 3rd party or external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Not sure what exactly you are looking for.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki

> The smartmontools package contains two utility programs (smartctl and smartd) to control and monitor storage systems using the Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology System (SMART) built into most modern ATA and SCSI harddisks. In many cases, these utilities will provide advanced warning of disk degradation and failure.

Comment: SMART is not the same as self-test. I am talking about sending the ATA-level commands to perform self-test on a device. I should also have mentioned I need to do it from C without the use of any 3rd party or external tools.